# how to autosize text in buttons wrapped into a linearlayout?

Tags: android-layout

I would like to autosize the text in a button. I tried with android:autosize properties in the layout, but did not succeed.
Can anyone help me?

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_bookmark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="12sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="5sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
        android:text="add bookmark longer text as expected!"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bookmarks_close"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="12sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="5sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_dialog_close_dark"
        android:text="close"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How it looks like in the Design view:

[image]

How it looks like on the device:

[image]

I expected the text to be smaller so that the text fits into the button.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there another parent layout. If LinearLayout has another parent layout then add full layout code here.

Comment: Are you sure you are using API 26 or above ? i.e the real device you using? because the android:autosize  is requires 26 or above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Support Library 26.0 provides full support to the autosizing TextView feature on devices running Android versions prior to Android 8.0 (API level 26). The library provides support to Android 4.0 (API level 14) and higher. The android.support.v4.widget package contains the TextViewCompat class to access features in a backward-compatible fashion.

Comment: Thanks. Any hint on how to autosize for api < 26?